# C# & HTML Agility Pack - Returning Null

Tags: c#, html, xcode, select, html-agility-pack

I want to make a console app that returns how many subscribers they have when I type in their channel. I currently have it downloading the search page as html from the Console.ReadLine(). This returns a html page successful as I added a .Save to see if the download had any output. However when scraping the html using xcode it returns null. I have tried many times using the Google Chrome copy xcode but have had no luck.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    public static void GetYoutubeSubscriptions2()
    {
        string url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + Regex.Replace(Console.ReadLine(), @"\s+", "+");

        Console.WriteLine(url);

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
        //document.Save(path1);

        var htmlNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//*[@id=""section - list - 231763""]/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/span[1]");

        foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Any help suggestions is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
var htmlNodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.HasClass("yt-subscriber-count"));
```

This is the `HasClass` extenstion

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
{
      var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
      var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
      return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For anyone else using this solution make sure you put the HasClass in a static class!